# Php Connection with mysql in .net Environment

Tags: php, .net, mysql

I am working on **.net** project i compiling some php code (with support of philanger).The thing is that i need to connect with `my_connect` but my php page does not able to find `mysql_connect` in intellisense or by writing `mysql_connect()` explicitly. I think i need some header file.

Can somebody suggest what i need to do to connect my php page to mysql database.

Comment: Please show the code concerning the connection.